# Unable to Publish a Post to Facebook Page Using Their API

Tags: javascript, facebook, postman

I was trying to publish something to Facebook page.

From this article, it seemed really easy to [publish using Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing)

So, I create a Facebook page and made sure that I **have all the required permission for the given auth token**, opened by Postman and created a POST request to following URL (along with attaching my access token bearer)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/2984640844138/feed?message=HeyWhatever
```

This is giving me following error

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \\\n          and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \\\n          requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \\\n          sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "D1z1soQbTE2"
   }
}
```

I am not sure about what I am doing wrong, perhaps my request is incorrect or I am not using postman correctly.

This is what I am doing in Postman (screenshot below), **can someone point me out what I am doing wrong? Also, suggestions are also welcome**

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure the API supports supplying the token via an `Authorization: Bearer …` header(?) - try and supply it as a normal request parameter with the name `access_token`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the Facebook [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), which provides you with the tools to generate the access token with appropriate permission and also craft your HTTP requests with ease. Visit the same, generate a token, then head to the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) to double check the scopes of the token.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I have the same problem as the OP and Access Token Debugger at least reveals that "publish_pages" is absent from the oauth token for some reason. (I am told by a user that they had granted my app the permission and are now unable to toggle it on in their facebook settings, which may be an unrelated issue).